# Is there a `let` or `as` keyword for Python generators?

Tags: python, syntax, clojure, generator

I'm coming to Python from Clojure, and was wondering if there is a way to have a "temporary variable" inside a generator.

In Clojure, I can use a `let` inside a for generator to name an intermediary computation on the item:

```lisp
(def fnames ["abc1234" "abcdef" "1024"])
(for [fname fnames
      :let [matches (re-matches #"(\w+?)(\d+)" fname)]
      :when matches]
  matches)
;=> (["abc10" "abc" "1234"] ["1024" "1" "024"])
```

In Python, I need to use a generator twice to filter out the `None` results:

```py
fnames = ["abc1234", "abcdef", "1024"]
matches = [re.match('(\w+?)(\d+)', fname) for fname in fnames]
matches = [match.groups() for match in matches if match is not None]
# [('abc', '1234'), ('1', '024')]
```

So, is there a way to do something like the following? If not, what is the most Pythonic way?

```py
matches = [re.match('(\w+?)(\d+)', fname) as match 
   for fname in fnames
   if match is not None]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no direct equivalent of Clojure's `let`.  The basic structure of Python's list comprehension is:

```
[name for name in iterable if condition]
```

where the `if condition` part is optional.  That is all that the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) provides for.

---

In your specific case though, you could put a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression) inside the list comprehension:

```
matches = [m.groups() for m in (re.match('(\w+?)(\d+)', f) for f in fnames) if m]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> fnames = ["abc1234", "abcdef", "1024"]
>>> matches = [m.groups() for m in (re.match('(\w+?)(\d+)', f) for f in fnames) if m]
>>> matches
[('abc', '1234'), ('1', '024')]
>>>
```

Also, you will notice that I removed the `is not None` part of your condition.  While it is generally a good idea to explicitly test for `None`, it is not needed in this case since `re.match` always returns either a match object (a truthy value) or `None` (a falsey value).

Comment: So, a more generic approach would be nesting generators? I don't know if it would be more readable than filter/map/reduce.

Comment: @BrunoKim - Yes.  In fact, generator expressions and list comprehensions are *preferred* by most Python programmers over using filter/map/reduce solutions.  There is even talk of removing the functions you listed from a future version of the language.  That said, you should still watch the length of your comprehensions.  Not everything needs to be done on one line. :)